# I don't use min-height in CSS

Tags: html, css, height, min

I don't use min-height command. I want to add data in section area. But I see the situation in this picture. When I am adding bigger things than section area, I see the situation in first picture.

[image]

Intented Situation:
[image]

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Sayfa Düzeni</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./script/style.css">

<style>
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#wrapper{
 margin:auto;
 max-width:900px;
 border-color:black;
 border-style:solid;
 min-height:500px;
 background-color:yellow;
}

header{
 max-width:900px;
 height:70px;
 border-color:gray;
 border-style:dashed;
 background-color:cyan;
}

nav{
 max-width:900px;
 height:50px;
 border-color:gray;
 border-style:dashed;
 background-color:pink
}

aside{
 float:left;
 width:150px;
 min-height:280px;
 border-color:gray;
 border-style:dashed;
 background-color:cyan;
}

section{
 float:left;
 width:738px;
 min-height:280px;
 border-color:gray;
 border-style:dashed;
 background-color:white;
}

footer{
 float:left;
 min-width:894px;
 min-height:76px;
 border-color:gray;
 border-style:dashed;
 background-color:pink;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Dağcılık ve Kış Sporları Ürünleri</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./script/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav>
  <a href="Anasayfa.html">Anasayfa</a>
  <a href="hizmetler.html">Hizmetlerimiz</a>
  <a href="ürünlerimiz.html">Ürünlerimiz</a>
  <a href="bizkimiz.html">Biz Kimiz?</a>
  <a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a>
  </nav>
  <aside>Yan Menü</aside>
  <section>
   Section
  </section>
  <footer>Sayfa Altı</footer>
 </div>


</body>

</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

for section css;

```
       width: 80.5%;

       overflow-y: scroll;
```

for aside css;

```
      width: 18%;
```